# Plotting Quantile Regression Lines

Tags: plot, regression, stata, quantile

In Stata, is it possible to plot quantile regression lines?  I know a standard OLS regression line can be added to a scatter plot but it isn't clear to me how to add other types of regression lines.

If that is not possible is, it possible to plot a line that I specify in the mx+b format?  Then I could just take the slope and intercept terms from the quantile regression output and plot them manually.

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Yes. Specifically, you can save the fitted values after model fitting, after which you plot those predicted values as an extra variable. Generally, `twoway function` allows plotting lines and curves given their formulas. I'll not illustrate the second method given the first.

```
. sysuse auto
(1978 Automobile Data)

. gen gpm = 1/mpg

. qreg gpm weight

 

. predict predicted
(option xb assumed; fitted values)

. scatter gpm weight || line predicted weight, sort ytitle("1 / `: var label mpg'") legend(off)
```